# Handle activity back stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 4 activities:

- MainActivity (launcher) - checks if user is logged in then start ContainerActivity else IntroActivity
- IntroActivity - shows various login methods including facebook login
- LoginActivity - contains phone or email login method. After successful login start ContainerActivity
- ContainerActivity - main application

I have 2 problems.

First, I want to remove `IntroActivity` from stack when user successfully login from `LoginActivity`. Can't use `android:noHistory="true"` because when user decides to use facebook to login not phone or email, `IntroActivity` should be in stack.

Second, when user logout from any activity, I want to back to `MainActivity` and clearing all back stack. I will add activities in future. What is the right way to do this?

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".intro.IntroActivity">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".authentication.LoginActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".intro.IntroActivity"
        android:noHistory="true" />
```

Comment: This is not a Firebase related issue. Please don't add tags that do not correspond with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove `IntroActivity` from stack after successful login, I would do this:

Assuming that `LoginActivity` should also be finished (removed from the stack) on successful login, you can call `startActivity()` to return to `IntroActivity` and add an "extra" to the `Intent` telling `IntroActivity` to start `ContainerActivity` and finish itself. Do this:

in `LoginActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("startContainerActivity", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

in `IntroActivity.onNewIntent()`:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("startContainerActivity")) {
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, ContainerActivity.class);
    startActivity(launchIntent);
    finish();
}
```

`IntroActivity` will then launch `ContainerActivity` and finish itself, leaving the stack: `MainActivity->ContainerActivity`.

To return to `MainActivity` from any other `Activity`, you just need to override `onBackPressed()` and return to `MainActivity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

When you specify the flags `CLEAR_TOP` and `SINGLE_TOP` this tells Android to remove all the activities on top of the target `Activity` and to reuse the target `Activity` (ie: not create a new instance of the target `Activity`). In this case, `onNewIntent()` is called on the existing instance of the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start IntoActivity using `startActivityForResult` and in LoginActivity after successfully loged in, you can set result `RESULT_OK` and in IntroActivity `onActivityResult` check for result code and finish IntoActivity.